# MySQL Query with three tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have got the following mySQL tables:

```
movies:
id,
title,
year

directors:
id,
name

directors_in_movies:
director_id,
movie_id
```

I would like to search for all the movies in which a director has been involved.
But I don't really know if I can combine three tables. I am quite new with databanks and I would be glad about some help how to write the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exists` operator should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM   movies m
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   directors_in_movies dim
               JOIN   directors d ON dim.director_id = d.id
               WHERE  dim.movie_id = m.id AND
                      d.name = 'Some Director')
```

Comment: Okay, I think that I didn't express my question precise enough. I have a director's name and want to get all the movies he was involved in. Does your SQL statement work for that?

Comment: @Chrissi You can add this condition to the inner query. See my edited answer.

Comment: I like to start the padiwans on joins, and then progress to the funky stuff.

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Strawberry If the movie has several co-directors, you'll get it multiple times if you use plain old joins

Comment: That's what distinct is for

Comment: @Strawberry to me using `distinct` with a `join` feels a bit counter-intuitive, but I guess it's a matter of taste really.